# Excel-VBA Find.replace with loop doesn't work correctly

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Im trying to epxort each row of an excel file to a new pdf file based on a docx template which contains the text that this macro will search and replace from relevant fields in an excel sheet.

The problem is the code only work correctly in first loop. After first loop, a 1.pdf file is exported with correct field from excel, but the template docx file is now saved with the data from excel as well which leads to the result later loops can't work correctly anymore. All excel fields of next row is all appended to the start of the template for some reason.

Please help me correct this code so that every time the loop run correctly. The desire result is each row of excel will only be exported to a new pdf file and the template docx is kept intact.

Thanks.

```
   Sub ReplaceText()
   Dim wApp As Word.Application
   Dim wDoc As Word.Document
   Dim z As Integer
   Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   wApp.Visible = True
   For z = 3 To 6

   Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("D:\test.docx")

 With wDoc
.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "TIEU_DE"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection = Range("B" & z)
.Application.Selection.EndOf

.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "ENGLISH"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection = Range("C" & z)
.Application.Selection.EndOf

.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "tenTG"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection = Range("D" & z)
.Application.Selection.EndOf

.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "Noidung"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
.Application.Selection = Range("E" & z)
.Application.Selection.EndOf

.SaveAs2 "D:\test.pdf", 17

.Close SaveChanges = False

  End With
  Next z

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to the below answers, my problem is solved by: First, using ".Close SaveChanges := False"; and Second, using "dotx as" template file format instead of "docx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.Close SaveChanges = False` gives me a compile error (variable not defined)

`.Close SaveChanges := False` works for me and doesn't save the changes.

The reason everything is copied to the start of the document in the next iteration is that the find.execute method doesn't move the selection (as it finds nothing) so the cursor stays at the beginning of the document but you still copy the cells.

Comment: Thanks. Added .Close SaveChanges := False makes it work, i didn't realise i miss the ":".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of test.docx use word template test.dotx (create it)

For saving pdf file use something like

```
        .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="D:\test" & z & ".pdf", ExportFormat:= _
wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True
```

And after than add

```
wDoc.Close saveChanges:=False
Set wDoc = Nothing
```

Comment: This is a very good idea. Using test.dotx makes a new document every time the code runs which helps prevent the template from being edited. Thanks a lot.